# Make "CS0642 C# Possible mistaken empty statement" be a compiler error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I've had this issue a couple times where I mistakenly append a semicolon to the end of an if statement, causing the block after the if statement to always execute. The compiler throws a warning shown in the title of this post, but I'm curious if I can tweak some settings so that this actually throws a compiler error when it is encountered?

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/760134/1663001

Comment: You can also add in the project properties under build tab add `642` into the *Specific warnings* box of *Treat warnings as errors*

Comment: Davidg, perfect, if you add this I'll mark it as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can do this at build time using the [`warnaserror`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/warnaserror-compiler-option) compiler flag. For example:

   ```
   csc /warnaserror:642
   ```
2. Configure the project using Visual Studio. Open project properties, *build* tab, under *Treat warnings as errors* select *Specific warnings* and enter `642` in the box. Note this setting is per build configuration so you could set it for `Debug` but not `Release` if you desire.

   [image]
3. As option 2 but editing the project file directly, add this line inside the `PropertyGroup` for the build configuration you want to change:

   ```
   <WarningsAsErrors>642</WarningsAsErrors>
   ```

Comment: This question was a duplicate, but this answer was better than those in the duplicate, IMO as it had more detail about different approaches. I think it would be worth migrating.

Comment: @JonHanna Yeah, I was considering answering on there, but the other question was ever so slightly different.

Comment: last clarification: do you use commas or semis to separate multiple entries here?

Comment: @BradyMoritz You would use commas e.g. `642,649,652`